# why a const object of an empty class cant be created

Tags: c++, constants, empty-class

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
   public:
      void foo() const {
          std::cout << "const version of foo" << std::endl;
      }
      void foo() {
          std::cout << "none const version of foo" << std::endl;
      }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  const A ac;
  a.foo();
  ac.foo();
}
```

The above code can't be compiled, could anyone of you tell me why?

Comment: Curious, this compiles in Visual Studio with no problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to initialize it. [This is a known problem with the spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#253).

Comment: What is the notion behind not allowing it?

Comment: I don't get the wording about user-provided default constructor. If there was empty `A::A()` provided would it compile?

Comment: @Gunner there just is no wording that allows the special case of an empty class to stay without an initializer or constructor. Classes with data members obviously need to be initialized if you have const objects created. @sharptooth, yes.

Comment: Ha!  Ten years after the defect was reported:  "This issue should be brought up again..."  I don't think this one's getting fixed for C++0x.

Comment: @James McNellis: I guess it doesn't bother anyone really - you add an empty default constructor and that's it.

Comment: @James: do you often build const object without any data member ? It would not cost much, but it's definitely an edge case. The fact that it depends on a constructor being defined is funny though (in a weird way).

Comment: @Matthieu:  Nah, and I don't think it should be a "high priority" thing to be fixed, since it's not so much a bug (like an inconsistency is a bug), it's a trivial annoyance.  I do think it's funny that it laid dormant for a decade then right before what is hopefully the last committee meeting before C++0x is finished it was commented on, though :-)

Comment: a silly doubt again on this old bug. Don't the  compiler generate the default constructor here? Wouldn't the default constructor be called at the line const A ac;  to initialize ac ?

Answer (score 4):

Initialize it as:

```
const A ac = A();
```

Working code : http://www.ideone.com/SYPO9

---

BTW, this is **not** initializaiton :  `const A ac(); //deceptive - not an initializaiton!`

Comment: You can also give A a user-defined constructor, even if it does nothing. The fact it has no constructor and the const is not initialised means it does not consider the object initialised.