# uninitialized const

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, constants, default-constructor

This compiles perfectly fine with the current MSVC compiler:

```
struct Foo
{
} const foo;
```

However, it fails to compile with the current g++ compiler:

```
error: uninitialized const 'foo' [-fpermissive]
note: 'const struct Foo' has no user-provided default constructor
```

If I provide a default constructor myself, it works:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}
} const foo;
```

Is this another case of MSVC being too permissive, or is g++ too strict here?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335836/why-a-const-object-of-an-empty-class-cant-be-created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a among others.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on GCC 4.6.1, with any dialect option. It only works if I install a member variable (like `int a;`), and the error is much more accurate: `‘const struct Foo’ has no user-provided default constructor and the implicitly-defined constructor does not initialize ‘int Foo::a’`

Comment: @KerrekSB: All I do is `g++ foo.cpp`, and `g++ --version` prints `g++ (GCC) 4.6.1`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Sorry, I meant GCC 4.6.2. Updated recently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The C++03 Standard:**

**8.5 [dcl.init] paragraph 9**

> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a user-declared default constructor.

From the above the error in gcc seems to be perfectly valid.

Comment: Note: if you would like an explanation as to why the way C-style implicit zero initialization for structs doesn't work in C++, it's because C and C++ implemented const differently, C++ had `const` before C did. See [this chat  transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/conversation/uninitialized-consts2) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

> `[2003: 8.5/9]:` **If no initializer is specified for an object, and the
>   object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type** (or array
>   thereof), **the object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of
>   const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a
>   user-declared default constructor. Otherwise,** if no initializer is
>   specified for a nonstatic object, the object and its subobjects, if
>   any, have an indeterminate initial value; **if the object or any of
>   its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.**

And:

> `[n3290: 8.5/11]:` **If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized;** if no initialization is
>   performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has
>   indeterminate value. [ *Note:* Objects with static or thread storage
>   duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2._ —end note_ ]
>
> `[n3290: 8.5/6]:` To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - **if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);**
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>
> **If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.**

So MSVC is more permissive here than both standards mandate.

Comment: That should be "allow" instead of "mandate" at the end, right?

Comment: @Deduplicator Same thing in the way I've used it IMO but we can make it "allow"

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the exact wording of the standard, but the error in g++ seems quite more sensible than the option of not saying anything. Consider this:

```
struct X {
   int value;
};
const X constant; // constant.value is undefined
```

Not in the case of a user provided default constructor (even if it does nothing) the compiler will call that constructor and the object will be *initialized* (by whatever definition of *initialized* you have implemented in your constructor).

Answer (score 1):

**C++17 Update**

C++17 adds some nuance to the requirement that const-qualified class types have a default constructor. The standard now defines the "const-default-constructable" concept:

> 7 To *default-initialize* an object of type T means:
>   (7.1) — If **T** is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated, and the best one for the *initializer*() is chosen through overload resolution. The constructor  thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the
>   object.
>   (7.2) — If **T** is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
>   (7.3) — Otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>   A class type **T** is const-default-constructible if default-initialization of T would invoke a user-provided constructor of T (not inherited from a base class) or if
>   (7.4) — each direct non-variant non-static data member **M** of **T** has a default member initializer or, if **M** is of class type **X** (or array thereof), **X** is const-default-constructible,
>   (7.5) — if **T** is a union with at least one non-static data member, exactly one variant member has a default member initializer,
>   (7.6) — if **T** is not a union, for each anonymous union member with at least one non-static data member (if any), exactly one non-static data member has a default member initializer, and
>   (7.7) — each potentially constructed base class of **T** is const-default-constructible.
>   If a program calls for the default-initialization of an object of a const-qualified type **T**, **T** shall be a const-default-constructible class type or array thereof.