# Compiler complaints for const object not initialized

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, default-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [uninitialized const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092670/uninitialized-const)

I understand that a const object needs to initialized.

So for the following code,

```
class sample
{};

int main()
{
   const sample obj;
   return 0;
}
```

the compiler will complain because the const object `obj` is not initialized.

But when i modify the code(show below) with a default constructor, the compiler will not throw any error.

```
class sample
{
    public:
       sample() { }
};

int main()
{
    const sample obj;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the thing that the newly added default ctor does which satisfies the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is the thing that the newly added default ctor does which satisfies the compiler?**

Because that is the requirement imposed by the C++ standard when declaring objects with the `const` qualifer.

**Reference:**

**C++03 8.5 Initializers    8 Declarators**
§9:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized; **if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a user-declared default constructor.** Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a nonstatic object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value90); if the object or any of its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: +1. This is more complete answer.

Comment: @Als: I could not understand from the standard. Could you explain the standard in your words. I do not understand the phrase `default-initialized` also.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: C++ standard classify's the declaration of an object in to 3 possible ways: **Default Initialization**,**Value Initialization** & **Zero Initialization**.The way you create your object amounts to Default Initialization.Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value/6032889#6032889) answer of mine might be of help to understand what each means.If not, do ask.

Comment: @Als: Thanks for the link. I am on track. Perhaps your answer to this question may help. Why can't the compiler generated ctor `default initialize` the const object in the first sample code?

Comment: @LinuxPenseur - The compiler generated constructor does not initialize types that the C language does not initialize. If it did, C++ would lose tons of benchmarks to C, all over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a default initialization of a const-qualified type. The C++ (C++11 draft n3290) standard has this to say about that (§8.5/6 Initializers):

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

Your first sample doesn't conform to this (no user-provided constructor). The second does.

Comment: +1 Good info. Also, there's a bug in MSVS 2008 :)